# Is it possible to set a Tile Map Service only by copying the folder structure to a hosted server?

Tags: tiles, gdal2tiles, tile-map-service

I used gdal2tiles to generate a directory with tiles of a bigger raster. Now, I'm able to see these local tiles on my browser, using the generated web pages (e.g. OpenLayers.html).

Thus, I copied the folder on a hosted server. The goal is to access the tiles with QGIS using the following an URL like `http://mysite.com/gis/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`. But I get no results.

Is it mandatory to configure the XML files (described here: [Tile Map Service Specification](https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification))? Or am I missing something simpler?

Answer (score 2):

That should work even without the XML file. You just need to add an XYZ layer with the URL template, but you might need to change `{y}` to `{-y}` if the tiles were generated with gdal2tiles. The minus indicates the Y numbering starts from the bottom.